# mysql query find highest score and use DISTINCT

Tags: php, mysql

My table is

```
+--------+------+-------+
| userId | tid  | score |
+--------+------+-------+
|  1     | 1    | 850   |
|  1     | 1    | 750   |
|  2     | 1    | 890   |
|  2     | 1    | 750   |
|  3     | 2    | 500   |
|  3     | 1    | 720   |
+--------+------+-------+
```

I need to give 3 prizes for 3 highest score in this table.Same userId Dont needed for other places. i need to fetch tid=1 highest score. Use DISTINCT for userID. what can i do..

Comment: What query you wrote?

Comment: please describe your question properly..??

Comment: highest 3 values needed and one highest value for one userId in tid=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply group by userId to get the result per user, and order by MAX(score) descending; since you're grouping by userId you'll get a list of users with their max score;

```
SELECT userid, MAX(score) score 
FROM scores
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY MAX(score) DESC;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7de36/2).

Comment: why you write max(score) in order by uou can simply write order by score.
SELECT userid, MAX(score) score 
FROM scores
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY score DESC;

Answer (score 1):

Try this. it will return all userid which have max value in descending order (highest to lowest)

```
SELECT userId, MAX(score) FROM table
GROUP BY userId ORDER BY MAX(score) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query.

SELECT distinct userId FROM scores where tId=1 order by score desc
limit 3;